# How to remove pins from Google Maps for closed businesses?

Tags: google-maps

In Google Maps I have stars or "visit later" (green flag) pins for many locations. Sometimes these businesses close or move and the data associated with the original location disappears completely. In this case the pins remain in Google Maps, but clicking on them just shows empty information, and I can't remove the pin the way I would for a normal business or location.

Is there any roundabout way I can remove pins like this?

Answer (score 2):

1. Click on `Saved` in the sidebar on the left:

[image: Saved]

2. Click on kebab menu (triple vertical dots) icon next to the list which you don't want to include the location -> `Edit list`:

[image: Kebab menu]

3. Click gray `X` icon next to the location you want to delete:

[image: X button]

Comment: Thank you! This seems to work for my starred locations, but not my green flag / "want to go" locations - after choosing "Edit List" nothing shows up. Still, better than nothing.